# how to extract data for discontinuous dates from NetCDF file?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a text file containing specific dates of an event from 1980 to 2018. i have NetCDF files of daily data from 1980-2018 as sing file i.e, 1980.nc, 1981.nc etc. i want to match dates in NetCDF file to that of text file. can anyone please help me?

my input text file is like:

```
   08-jan-1979
.
.
.
   21-dec-2018
```

and i have another NetCDF file with data from 1979 jan to dec 2018. what i want to do is match the dates from text file to the NetCDF file and extract data for only these specified dates.

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/636142/100397

Comment: Given your [other netCDF question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632744/100397) had no takers I think it's likely that no-one here uses netCDF. In this case you're going to need to help us along. How do we get date-based data out of a netCDF file? What does it look like? We can help you with pattern matching but unless we know what it is that we need to match we cannot help you. Some examples of what you yourself have tried would also be courteous